# How to make my application on for a period of time ?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a code for an android application, this application must be ON (the window ON)for 15 minutes, How i can do this ?
The Idea of being on is that this application is used for automated attendance
 that uses NFC tags,when the student swipes the tag over the smartphone ,the application take the record,but the problem is that the smartphone can't read from the tag if it's not open (I mean the app appears in front and the window has light )

Sorry for the poor English language.

Comment: check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any body wants to solve this problem, you need to write this line of code
in the OnCreat method: 
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);